# Problem to upload image from Angular to php

Tags: php, angular, image, upload

I'm trying to upload an image from an angular application with php backend, but the file arrive as null to backend.

```
fileUploaded(event) { // called each time file input changes
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList && fileList[0]) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]); // read file as data url
      this.format.File = file;
      reader.onload = (ev) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.format.Picture = ev.target['result'];
      }
    }  
  }
```

This is the caller to the service

```
createFormat(){
    this.format.Label = this.format.Name;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('formatLogo', this.format.File);
    this.formatService.uploadLogo(formData).subscribe()
  }
```

this is the service.
I tried to use Content-Type also, with the same result

```
uploadLogo(formData){

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = { headers: headers }
    return this.http.post(this.formatsPath + '/uploadLogo', formData, options);
  }
```

This is the request payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryUlyYDb5WjslMf3nw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formatLogo"; filename="fileName.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryUlyYDb5WjslMf3nw--
```

This is the server side

```
    function uploadLogo(){
        $name = $_FILES['formatLogo']['name'];
--code--
    }
```

The server side, obviosly, have more things to do. But the simple file is empty, so it's not useful to post everything.

I can't get the mistake. :'(

Someone smarter than me can provide his help? Please

Comment: What are you sending a request header `enctype` for? That does not even officially exist as a defined HTTP request header, AFAIK. You might want to try `Content-Type` …?

Comment: Hi CBroe, i tried both with the same result. In the last try was enctype, so in the copy & paste this remains. I will update the post telling this thing

Comment: Can you do a bit of client-side debugging then, to check what the request that gets actually made looks like? And maybe also if your `formData` object actually contained what you expected it to?

Comment: If I look at it in the browser debug it seems empty, but in the request payload of the post http it is popolated with the correct values
------WebKitFormBoundaryUlyYDb5WjslMf3nw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formatLogo"; filename="fileName.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryUlyYDb5WjslMf3nw--

Comment: Try and check what $_FILES actually contains (if anything), make a `var_dump` debug output of it.

Comment: the var_dump($_FILES) is: array(0){}

Comment: Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, to see if you are really dealing with a POST request in the first place then. (Sometimes unintended redirects are the cause for problems like this, causing the client to follow the initial POST with a GET request.)

Comment: echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST"

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58118536/11457981